# Prepopulate data with db

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios4

I want to have pre populated db with data for my application.

but i am not sure the best way to that.Do i need to create db at launch and populate data from a file or do i need to have db added into the resources file with data loaded. i want to read & write into the db

Pls let me know your opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add db file as resource. Add your data to the database file , then add the database to resources.

For reading from database, you can read it directly from resource bundle. If you want to write to database , then you must move the database file to Documents or Library Directory of your application.